# 30s of inactivity timeout will close logon screen

Tags: windows-10, login, login-screen

In Windows 10 logon screen (not remote), an inactive time of 30s will close it. Is there any way to modify the time?

We are developing some MFA (multi-factor authentication) support, after entering the user password it will have other challenge like email/phone calls. But in some cases it may take more than 30s, Windows 10 will close the logon screen and stop any email/phone waiting.

Comment: Can you enable the escape key to work again instead of waiting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a customer with paid MS support account.

The registry controlling the login screen timeout is:

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI
DWORD Value: IdleTimeOut
Unit: msec
```

Comment: FYI, the max value in 120 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Changing Windows 10 lockscreen timeout requires a registry tweak, after adding the setting, you’ll then set your timeout using the standard Power Options applet in the Control Panel.

Warning on using Registry Editor, misusing it can render your system unstable or even inoperable.

In Registry Editor navigate to the following key:

```
HKEYLOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7
```

Double click the Attributes value to open its properties window.

Change the "Value data" box from 1 to 2, and then click OK.

Next step will be changing the timeout setting using Power Options.

Open up Power Options using Windows key + R and enter powercfg.cpl and click OK.

In the Power Options window, click the “Change plan settings” link next to whatever power plan you’re using.

In the Edit Plan Settings window, click the “Change advanced power settings” link.

In the Power Options dialog, expand the “Display” item and you’ll see the new setting you added listed as “Console lock display off timeout.” Expand that and you can then set the timeout for however many minutes you want.